# View customization in a pushed view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

For a controller that is pushed by a nav controller, if in its desired `init` method you create the details of the pushed controller's view, my understanding is that if the view is removed later because it is offscreen (due to low memory, for example), you may never see it again since the `init` is only called once when loading the view controller, and subsequent pushes may show nothing.

It would seem a better place for this view setup is in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, that way it will be recreated correctly if the controller needs to build the view the next time it is pushed.

Yet I see tutorials that often put the pushed view controller's view setup in its `init` method; how important is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View setup should be done in `viewDidLoad` (or in `loadView` if you're not using a nib), for exactly the reason you're describing.  If you need to know the controller's top-level view dimensions to set up the subviews, then do it in `viewWillAppear:`.

Usually, a view controller that is popped is immediately deallocated; if the app needs to show the same view later, it creates a new view controller for it.  So in that scenario, the app won't show “nothing”.

If the app pushes or presents another view controller on top of the first view controller, the first view controller's view can be unloaded.  If the app *never* pushes or presents a second view controller over the first view controller, the first view controller's view can't be unloaded until the controller is popped, at which time (in most apps) the controller is deallocated anyway.  So in that case, setting up the view in `init` won't cause trouble.

But it's still bad design to set up views in `init`.  You might change your app later to push or present a second view controller, thus creating unexpected unsafe behavior.

Also, it's common to create a view controller, set properties on it, and then push it.  If the properties affect the controller's view hierarchy, then `init` is too early to set up the views.